# Can't get an element's value by class name with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a patient number that is posted on my website coming from a Caspio database.  I want to pull this number and save it as a Javascript var patientNumber.  I have tried to do this by ClassName, ID, Name and nothing works.  I get 'undefined' returned to me.

Here is a screenshot from the Inspector screen.
https://recordit.co/MUAGMqpUgn

The HTML tag I'm targeting:

```html
<dd class="cbResultSetData cbResultSetNestedAlign">ClinicA11-PF-TR1-P1</dd>
```

Here is the code I've tried.

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_head', function () { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">  
function getPatientNumber(){  
    var patientNumber;
/*  var patientNumber = document.getElementsByName('DataCtnr');*/
    var patientNumber = document.getElementsByClassName("dd.cbResultSetData.cbResultSetNestedAlign")[0];
/*  var patientNumber=document.getElementById("cbTable_51135f773f94b4");  */
    alert(patientNumber);
}
</script>
<?php } );
```

Comment: `patientNumber=document.getElementsByClassName("cbResultSetData")[0].innerText` you need to write innerText at the end of element

Comment: For that string you'll want `document.querySelector(...)` instead. Once you have that, get its `.textContent`

Comment: `dd.cbResultSetData.cbResultSetNestedAlign` is not a class name

Comment: Thank you!  The .innerText and .textContent both worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add innerText at the end of this line - `var patientNumber = document.getElementsByClassName("dd.cbResultSetData.cbResultSetNestedAlign")[0];` like this

```
var patientNumber = document.getElementsByClassName("dd.cbResultSetData.cbResultSetNestedAlign")[0].innerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expression:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("dd.cbResultSetData.cbResultSetNestedAlign")
```

will not select the element you are seeking. As written, it is looking for elements with:

```
class="dd.cbResultSetData.cbResultSetNestedAlign"
```

which is not your desired element.

This expression:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("cbResultSetData cbResultSetNestedAlign")
```

will select all elements with:

```
class="cbResultSetData cbResultSetNestedAlign"
```

But to select the first `<dd>` element with those classes, you can use:

```
document.querySelector("dd.cbResultSetData.cbResultSetNestedAlign");
```

which will select the first element that looks like this:

```
<dd class="cbResultSetData cbResultSetNestedAlign">
```

```js
let dd = document.querySelector('dd.cbResultSetData.cbResultSetNestedAlign');
console.log('dd:', dd);

let results = document.getElementById('results');
results.innerHTML = dd.innerHTML;
```

```html
The DD tag:<br/>
<dd class="cbResultSetData cbResultSetNestedAlign">ClinicA11-PF-TR1-P1</dd>

<br/>
Results: <span id="results"></span>
```

Comment: @Cecilia You're very welcome, I'm glad I could help.